# How to rotate Vector3 in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

I have to different vectors (**Vector3**) **V1** and **V2**.

Need to rotate **V1** to make it looking at **V2.normalized** direction.

Some of **Quaternion** class methods are deprecated now, so the all that I've found is out of date.

Comment: As I've mentioned in tags I'm using C#

Comment: You also mentioned in your tags that you were using unityscript, hence my question.

Comment: Then don't tag Unityscript which is another language supported by Unity. Fixed it for you. It would be good to post your current code. It doesn't matter if it's deprecated or not. It's still  useful .

Comment: ok, thanks for that

Comment: So what have you found so far? Anything you tried already? And are those Vectors `v1` and `v2` supposed to represent **directions** or **positions**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming V1 and V2 are both directions, you want V1 to look in the same direction as V2, but maintain it's length:

```
V1 = V2.normalized * V1.magnitude; // direction from V2, length from V1
```

If you want a smooth transition:

```
target = V2.normalized * V1.magnitude;
V1 = Vector3.Lerp(V1, target, Time.deltaTime); // this dampens towards the end
```

If you want V1 to be a direction pointing to the position V2, then I don't see why you would want to normalize V2. But anyway: [Quaternion.LookRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html)

```
V1 = Quaternion.LookRotation(V2 - V1, Vector3.up).eulerAngles;
```